# Automate Users not logged in 60 days script

Tags: powershell, active-directory

[image: Powershell script]

Linked is a Powershell Script that I am Using to find the Users that did not log on in the past 60 days. I am new in learning powershell, but is there a way to automate this process by creating a batch file or, automate it to where when it finds a users t gets sent to a mail ?

Comment: PLEASE fix your code. wrap it in code formatting markers - the how-to on that is linked on the page you used to create your Question.

Comment: Write your code in the stack overflow editor not link a picture!

Comment: What is your question, it was never explicitly stated. Yes you have a code that checks for users inactive for 60 days, so what? What are you trying to do, what do you want us to help you with and **what is your question**! Please edit your question to make it clearer